# Is work_queue thread safe?

Tags: linux, kernel

Looking at workqueue.c it appears as though only parts that are locked properly are between the publicly exposed APIs and the internal thread that runs.  There seem to be some things outside the critical section (which to my untrained eye) that could be unsafe?

Am I correct or way off base?

Comment: Could you be a bit more specific?

Comment: There are no critical sections in kernel. There are only semaphores, spin-locks, reader-writer variant of both, completions, irqsaves, atomic operations, memory barriers, careful ordering and per-CPU data structures. Each of them has precisely defined set of cases it solves and precisely defined set of contexts where it can be used, so it's not even possible to use one thing for locking the whole thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I presume you are talking about workqueue.c in the Linux kernel?
http://lxr.linux.no/#linux+v3.2.9/kernel/workqueue.c

In that case, only use the public API, assume it is threadsafe and report any issues you see to Ingo Molnar. Note that most kernel developers are seriously smart and will not redo the "big lock" mistake ever again: not everything is run under a mutex because not everything needs to. Tricks like RCU (read copy update) also reduce the amount of locking needed.
And everything without a lock will perform a lot better.